# Webpack - JS - custom dist folder structure

Tags: webpack

I need help on my webpack configuration.

Currently, I have a common project that will serve multiple website.

By default, templates are located here : js\pages\XXX.js

if an override file is found in this location : js\pages\overrides\SiteName\XXX.js with the same Js name, I will use the override file.

Currently, this is working. I'm able to generate all the entry points with overrides/default js (cf code below).

**What i can't do**

Inside the dist folder, I would like to create a different folder architecture base on the site Name. Here is what i want to achieve

dist

- home.js (default for all different website)
- site2
- - home.js
- site5
- - home.js

**Code**

```
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
      home: [
        XXX\src\main\resources\static\js\pages\home.js',    
      ],
      home_site2: [
        XXX\src\main\resources\static\js\pages\overrides\site2\home.js',
      ],
      home_site5: [
        XXX\src\main\resources\static\js\pages\overrides\site5\home.js',
      ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: resolvePath.dist,
        publicPath: resolvePath.publicPath
    }
}
```

Note: I was able to perfom it in css by using rules

Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

### TLDR;

You can find a working example at this [StackBlitz app.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-t1pdnx?file=webpack.config.js)

---

### Explanation

Let's start with how the config file will look like:

#### webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');

// We're doing this import so that we can get autocompletion.
/**
 * @type {import("webpack/types").Configuration}
 */
const config = {
  entry: {
    home: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'home.js'),
    home_site2: path.join(__dirname, 'src/overrides/site2', 'home.js'),
    home_site5: path.join(__dirname, 'src/overrides/site5', 'home.js')
  },

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: fileData => {
      const { chunk } = fileData;
      if (!chunk.entryModule) {
        return crtPath;
      }

      const { userRequest: req } = chunk.entryModule;
      const siteNameDelimiter = 'overrides/';
      if (req.includes(siteNameDelimiter)) {
        fileData.chunk = null;
        fileData.filename = req.slice(
          req.indexOf(siteNameDelimiter) + siteNameDelimiter.length
        );

        return '[path][name].js';
      }

      return '[name].js';
    },

    // Emit fresh files every time.
    clean: true
  },

  mode: 'development'
};

module.exports = config;
```

Firstly, it's important to mention that each item in the `entry` object will result in a **new chunk**. That's why at the end of the bundling process, there will be 3 files.
Let's also clarify what a **chunk** is. A chunk can be thought of as a group of modules. The chunks which are associated with the **entry items** can be called **main chunks**. There are other types of chunks, for example when you use the `import()` function, a new chunk will be created. However, the main chunk differentiates itself from the other chunks by having injected code by webpack, also called **runtime code**. That additional code is responsible for lazily loading other chunks, handling the loading of a chunk and so forth. Other chunks have some runtime code too, but it's too little compared to the amount which a main chunk has.

Towards the end of the bundling process, the **chunks assets** are created. By an *asset* it is meant the resulting file of a chunk, which also contains all the necessary code. This part is also where the *final path* of a chunk is determined.

It happens in the [`TemplatedPathPlugin.js` file](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/main/lib/TemplatedPathPlugin.js#L119). Here we can also see the available placeholders:

```js
const replacePathVariables = (path, data, assetInfo) => {
  /* ... */
  
  // Filename context
    //
    // Placeholders
    //
    // for /some/path/file.js?query#fragment:
    // [file] - /some/path/file.js
    // [query] - ?query
    // [fragment] - #fragment
    // [base] - file.js
    // [path] - /some/path/
    // [name] - file
    // [ext] - .js
    if (typeof data.filename === "string") { /* ... */ }

  // Compilation context
  /* ... */

  // Chunk context
  /* ... */
}
```

For the current situation, the `Filename context` section is the one of interest.

Here is once again the configuration for the `output` option:

```js
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
  filename: fileData => {
    const { chunk } = fileData;
    if (!chunk.entryModule) {
      return crtPath;
    }

    const { userRequest: req } = chunk.entryModule;
    const siteNameDelimiter = 'overrides/';
    if (req.includes(siteNameDelimiter)) {
      fileData.chunk = null;
      fileData.filename = req.slice(
        req.indexOf(siteNameDelimiter) + siteNameDelimiter.length
      );

      return '[path][name].js';
    }

    return '[name].js';
  },

  // Emit fresh files every time.
  clean: true
},
```

Notice that `output.filename` no longer is a string value, but a function. The function is invoked immediately before the `TemplatedPathPlugin`'s logic is factored in.
So, in the case where the initial files are under the `overrides` directory, the resulting chunk path will be of this form:

```js
/* ... */
// [base] - file.js
// [path] - /some/path/
// [name] - file
/* ... */
const siteNameDelimiter = 'overrides/';
  if (req.includes(siteNameDelimiter)) {
    fileData.chunk = null;
    fileData.filename = req.slice(
      req.indexOf(siteNameDelimiter) + siteNameDelimiter.length
    );

    return '[path][name].js';
  }
/* ... *
```

In our case, `path` is whatever comes after `overrides/` in the entry path and name refers to whatever is between the last `/` and `.js`.
For instance, in `src/overrides/site2/home.js`, `path = site2/` and `name = home`, so `'[path][name].js' = 'site2/home'`.

And now another important aspect: whatever the returned path is(for instance `'home.js'`, `'site2/home'`), it will be appended to the value of `output.path`, which in this case refers to:

```js
path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
```

So, the final paths for the chunks are:

- home -> `dist/home.js`
- home_site2 -> `dist/site2/home.js`
- home_site5 -> `dist/site5/home.js`